# Trim extra space with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using PHP tidy and it automatically indents markup, adds tabs and spaces. Please take a look at this.

http://jsfiddle.net/njh85/

I got 2 questions:

- How to remove this extra spaces from selected option (The reason is PHP tidy library: adds extra space to indent markup. But I can't turn it off, so I'm searching some JS solution to trim text)

[image]

- How to make "Select one" to act as HTML5 placeholder?

Comment: can't you put options inline ? ie : `<option value="#">Select one...</option>`

Comment: @epic_syntax als read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work on editing below 2000rep `edit privilege`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting spaces because your options' text is on a separate line in HTML with indenting. You could remove them first:

```
$("#users option").text(function(i, text) {
    return $.trim(text);
});
```

As for the placeholder, use `.attr("placeholder", ...)` instead of `.val(...)`:

```
input = $( "<input>" )
    .appendTo( wrapper )
    .attr( "placeholder", value )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/njh85/6/

Comment: Don't know why: trim works on JSfiddle but not on my page with same code. What can be issue?

Comment: @epic_syntax: Any error in the console? Might be necessary to use `jQuery.trim` instead.

Comment: No. I found issue: Must be value = $.trim(selected.val() ? selected.text() : ""), on line 12

Answer (score 2):

How about using [$.trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) :

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/njh85/3/)

Comment: Select some diferent option, trim doesn't work on second selection

Comment: You'll have to use trim on all your input values, and you're code is to extensive for me to go trough to find all instances where you insert data and wrap it with trim, you can do that yourself ?

Comment: It's not soltion. My JS knowledge is not good enough that's why I posted question

Comment: Thx very very much. And what about second question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15815/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-adeneo)

Answer (score 1):

As of JavaScript 1.8.1 (ES5) you can use normal [string.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

```
var orig = "   foo  ";
alert( orig.trim() );

// "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look @ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: @EliranM. Hes using jquery in his question

Answer (score 0):

Trim left and right spaces of a string

```
string.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
```

Regarding to placeholder, you can try [jQuery-Placeholder](https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder)